# How to collect only one value from a JToggleButton when a mouse moves over the container?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, jbutton

I am working on doing a word finder puzzle game. When I am trying to get to happen is a user clicks on a letter then moves his mouse across other letters to create a word. I am having some problems with the listeners. I have been going back and fourth using mouseDragged and mouseMoved. So far mouseMoved seems to work better because it dynamically grabs values. The problem is I can't figure out how to get it only grab one value. In an ideal world it would move of a Button or label grab that value once and ignore the value till it reaches a new button or label. Currently it just grabs values at every instant a mouse is on that container. The logic for my Mouse method is below:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    int count = countClicked;
    int num = 0;
    for(JToggleButton row : puzzleGrid){
        if(e.getComponent() == row && count == 1) {
            if(num == 0){
                num++;
            for(JLabel l: solWords)
            {
                sb.append(row.getText());
                System.out.println(l.getText()+" = "+ sb.toString());
                if(l.getText().contentEquals(row.getText()))
                    System.out.println(row.getText());
            }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I am using the value gathered from the containers to check against an array of JLabels containing the solution values.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last letter in a static variable:

```
static String lastLetter = null;

mouseMoved(...) {

    if(row.getText().equals(lastLetter)) {
        continue;
    }
    lastLetter = row.getText();

}
```